# Changing the statusBar color to light in specific ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I've researched the internet and found out how i'm suppose to do however when i try it nothing seem to happen. it is still dark? what am i doing wrong?

1. Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `YES`
2. set `self.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()` in `ViewDidLoad`
3. add below code.

   ```
   override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Set `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO`.
and can set like this

```
navigationViewController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle. LightContent
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible something else is overriding your setting. For example, if you're in a navigation controller, you might find you need to subclass `UINavigationController` to have *that* set the status bar colour.

Comment: so i need to subclass my navigationController and then insert the code in there or what?

Answer (score 0):

Use it in `viewWillAppear`

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarStyle(.LightContent, animated: false)
```